# How to make a mask of gradient from nontransparent source pixels

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, mask

I have a skyline as background in a game. The skyline has fully transparent areas and opaque areas and maybe some semitransparent areas... :-P

This time I'd like to create a gradient to place on top of the skyline, so that I can easily make the skyline darker/brighter, tint the color of it to fake different times of day, sky colors tinting it etc...

For this I need to make a gradient that is the same size of the skyline, but does not draw where the skyline is fully transparent.

I guess there would be maybe a few ways to do this, and avoiding photoshopish ways, I think I'm gonna try to render the skyline by using CCRenderTexture and/or possibly masking a gradient (preferrably CCGradientLayer that I could easily tint later) where the skyline is fully transparent. But I'm not very used to CCRenderTexture...

Any simple solution?

Comment: i'd probably look at writing a shader for the skyline sprite ... to apply some tint processing as a function of each pixel's "a" component and position (gradient).

Comment: You should use CoreGraphics masking.  (1) Make a CGImage from the image file for the skyline.  (2) Use CoreGraphics to mask on that CGImage to make a CGImage that is white where the skyline is, and transparent otherwise.  (3) Create a CCSprite from the mask CGImage.  (4) Change color and opacity of the CCSprite (optional: with animation) to create the desired effect